# Call scalar function from Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have scalar valued function - fn_GetTaskTime(int). So I want to use returned value in result of select statement. Also I have table called tblTask looks like:

```
id|TaskName|ParentTask
----------------------
 1|Task1   |-1
 2|Task1.2 |1
 3|Task2   |-1
```

I'm trying like this:

```
select id, taskName, parentTask, dbo.fn_GetTaskTime(id) as Time from dbo.tblTasks
```

and  get error - "Invalid object name 'tblTask'". 
Result of function is integer. And I want to have result like:

```
id|TaskName|ParentTask|Time
---------------------------
 1|Task1   |-1        | 20
 2|Task1.2 |1         | 10
 3|Task2   |-1        | 35
```

So what I can do?

Comment: Show you function code. try this query SELECT dbo.fn_GetTaskTime(1)

Comment: It looks like the code within `GetTaskTime` is referencing the nonexistent `tblTask` where it *should* be referencing the pluralized `tblTasks`.

Comment: The Sql query you have put references 'dbo.tblTasks' while the error says "Invalid object name 'tblTask'". The 2 table names look similar.Must be incorrect spelling in the function.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Thank you very much. This my boner. Mistake realy was in spelling.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message;

```
"Invalid object name 'tblTask'". Result of function is integer
```

Error seem to be with your `tblTask`.

I guess the table does not exist, since your query is targeting `tblTasks` (plural). 
Please verify that the table being called in the function `fn_GetTaskTime()` is not calling **tblTask** but **tblTasks**.